Template function overloading behavior changes with function declaration order
I have the following C++ code which outputs 12:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T foo(T val) {
  return val;
}

template<typename T>
T bar(T n) {
  return foo(n);
}

int foo(int val) {
  return 1;
}

int main() {
  cout<<foo(2)<<bar(2)<<endl;
  return 0;
}

If I change the definition of bar to
int bar(int n) {
  return foo(n);
}

without changing its position, the output is still 12.
However, if I move the definitions of bar to just before main, the output changes to 11. (compiler: g++ 14.1.1)
My question is:

Why does bar(2) call the template version of foo instead of the non-template overload even if both of them seem to be viable when bar is instantiated?
How can I modify the code to output 11 without changing the order of function definitions while maintaining the generality of the template foo definition?


A follow-up question:
If foo is independent and looked up at the first stage, why should the following code compile?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct C {};

template<typename T>
T bar(T n) {
  return foo(n);
}

C foo(C val) {
  std::cout << "foo\n";
  return {};
}

int main() {
  bar(C());
  return 0;
}


"Why does bar(2) call the template version of foo..." Because at the point foo(n), only the function template version of foo is visible. So there is no option but to call the tempated version.

Also one question per post. C++ is a very complex language and the answer can be vastly different for the same looking thing. You're considering so many cases at once.

Two-phase name lookup. The name foo is looked up at the point of definition of bar, and the template overload is found; the non-template overload is not visible yet. The name is looked up again at the point of instantiation, but using argument-dependent lookup only. And since int doesn't have an associated namespace, the non-template overload of foo is not found.


Why does bar(2) call the template version of foo

In the original case, at the point where foo(n) is called, only the function template version of foo is viable. Even though there is two-phase lookup, there is no associated namespace for int as int is a built in type. That is, the non-templated version is not added to the candidate list here.
If you were to have a class type parameter instead of int, the call to foo(n) in the original case would've called the non-templated foo (demo), because this time through, argument dependent lookup in phase two would have seen the non-template foo is also a viable candidate.

In the second case, when you move the definition of bar to just before main, both versions (templated and non-template) are visible for foo(n). And since a non-template version is preferred over the templated version, we see 11.


How can I modify the code to output 11 without changing the order of function definitions while maintaining the generality of the template foo definition?

You can add a forward-declaration for the non-templated foo before bar, as shown below:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T foo(T val) {
  return val;
}

int foo(int val);     //added this declaration

template<typename T>
T bar(T n) {
  return foo(n);
}

int foo(int val) {
  return 1;
}

int main() {
  cout<<foo(2)<<bar(2)<<endl; //now this prints 11
  return 0;
}



Thanks. But why does this code compile if foo is looked up at the first stage?

@YuqiHuang Because in the second phase through ADL the non-templated version becomes viable and is preferred over the templated version. Note you demo is essentially the same as the demo in my answer where I explained that through ADL when the argument is a class type, the non-templated foo can be used.

So you mean that two-phase lookup is actually a matter of priority? But as "In the first phase, all non-dependent names are resolved (looked up)." and foo is not dependent, why doesn't it produce a compile error?

n is dependent so foo(n) will find the non-templated  foo in the second phase.  I would also recommend using a good c++ book as there you'll find many other exmaples and more details explanation since c++ is one of the most difficult/complicated programming language to learn. The example and explanation in the answer should also help in clearing up what is going on but still in the books there will be more example and in comment section there is word limit to write.

Thanks a lot anyway. I found my question included in the Lookup rules section of the Dependent names page on CppReference, which may be helpful to understand this topic.

@YuqiHuang Yes exactly, that is why I said n is dependent in my previuos comment and so is foo(n) . We have dependent names and expressions. And many other things as well. You're welcome.
